# Quantum dynamics on varieties and Salmon Prizes

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

### <strike>Concluding</strike> Progressive Remarks

A new finding is Bates and Oeding's preprint "Toward a salmon conjecture" ([arXiv:1009.6181](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.6181)), with its reference to the [Salmon Prize](http://www.dms.uaf.edu/~eallman/Papers/salmonPrize.pdf).

The Salmon Prize (photo of the prize [here](http://www.dms.uaf.edu/~eallman/Papers/IMAchallenge_and_reward.pdf)) is offered by mathematician/biologist [Elizabeth Allman](http://www.dms.uaf.edu/~eallman/), and can be appreciated in the broad mathematical context that is provided by [Topics in Tensors: A Summer School by Shmuel Friedland](http://www.mat.uc.pt/~cmf/SummerSchool/TopicsInTensors.htm).

---

Until such time as further comments are offered, a working answer is:

1. An introduction to multilinear varieties considered as algebraic/geometric objects may be found on page 99ff of Joe Harris' [*Algebraic Geometry: a First Course*](http://books.google.com/books?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC&pg=PA99).
2. A recent comprehensive survey is chapter 7 of Joseph Landsberg's brand-new book [*Tensors: Geometry and Applications*](http://books.google.com/books?id=JTjv3DTvxZIC&pg=PA173) (December 2011), which begins (encouragingly)

   > "This chapter includes nearly all that is known about defining equations for secant varieties of Segre and Veranese varieties …"
3. At the conclusion of the meta thread that was started by Andy Putman (who wondered why this question was being downvoted) concrete examples now are given of higher-order ['almost-Hilbert' varieties](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1307/question-about-second-hand-lions-quantum-dynamics-etc/).  The following intent is posted there:

   > Last night I discovered a brand-new monograph by Joseph Landsberg that encompasses more-or-less the answer sought, and so I have amended the beginning of the question to be a pointer to Landsberg's monograph.
   >
   > Sometime in the next week or two I will post a concrete mathematical question — framed within the context that Landsberg's monograph supplies — asking for a classification of all multilinear varieties having unit-dimension defect with respect to their natural Segre embedding.
   >
   > At that time I will request closure of the original question, to be supplanted by this classification question.
4. A shorter, accessibly written, and free-as-in-freedom introduction to these multilinear varieties is Joseph Landsberg's relatively recent — and  much-cited — *Bulletin of the AMS* survey article "[Geometry and the complexity of matrix multiplication](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2008-45-02/S0273-0979-08-01176-2/home.html)" (2008).

Please let me apologize for the deficiencies of original question in conveying to MOF readers the mathematical depth and breadth of these multilinear varieties, their implications for fundamental quantum physics, and their numerous practical applications in engineering fields ranging from the computational complexity matrix multiplication to the simulation of quantum transport.

Fortunately, Joseph Landsberg's recent writings have done an immensely better job of this than the original draft of my MOF question did!

My appreciation and thanks are extended to all who have provided comments, and in particular, sincere congratulations are extended to Theo Johnson-Freyd for providing [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88133/harris-algebraic-geometry-quantum-dynamics-on-varieties-and-a-more-than-mone/88146#88146) that has received MOF's first-ever [Gold Reversal Medal](https://mathoverflow.net/badges/95/reversal).  It has been great fun to help this happen!

---

#### The question asked (as clarified per Joseph Landsberg)

For the theorem of algebraic geometry that is specified below, please provide a reference (or references) that:

1. states the theorem rigorously,
2. proves the theorem explicitly,
3. within a framework that extends naturally to multi-linear algebraic varieties

---

#### The theorem for which mathematical references are sought

Let $k\ge1$ be an integer and let $\boldsymbol{\psi}=\{\psi_{(mn)}\}$ and $\boldsymbol{\xi}=\{\xi_{(srm)}\}$ be vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{k^2}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{2(k-1)k}$ respectively.  Here ${(}\dots{)}$ is a multi-index, repeated indices are summed, and the indices $\{s,r,m,n\}$ range over $s \in \{1,2\}$, $r \in \{1,\dots,k-1\}$, and $m,n \in \{1,\dots,k\}$.  Then we have:

> **The Second-Hand Lion Theorem (SHLT)**
>   $$
> %\forall\ \boldsymbol{\psi}\ \colon\ \ 
> \det_{mn}\ \psi_{(mn)} = 0 
> \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 
> \exists\ \boldsymbol{\xi}\ \colon\ \  
> \psi_{(mn)} = \xi_{(1rm)}\,\xi_{(2rn)}.
> $$

---

#### Context of the question in multilinear algebraic geometry

Primary consideration should be given to references that prove the theorem and/or discuss related theorems within a mathematical framework that extends naturally to multilinear algebraic varieties.

Secondary consideration should be given to references that are reasonably accessible to the (many) engineers and physicists for whom these multilinear varieties increasingly are finding practical applications.

In the context of algebraic geometry, $r$ may be regarded as an index over $(k{-}1)$ order-2 Segre varieties that enter in a rank-$(k{-}2)$ secant join having the natural Segre embedding in the tensor product space $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$.

In the notation of Joe Harris' [*Algebraic Geometry: a First Course*](http://books.google.com/books?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC&pg=PA99), the theorem asserts the identity of the preceding Segre embedding with what is called the *generic determinantal variety* $\mathcal{M}^{(kk)\!}_{k{-}1}$ that comprises (by definition) the set of $k\times k$ complex matrices having matrix rank $k-1$.

Attention is directed particularly to a passage in Harris ([page 100](http://books.google.com/books?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC&pg=PA100)) that states:

> "We should draw a fundamental and important distinction between bi- and tri- or multilinear objects […] whose invariants are far from being completely understood."

Thus, although the theorem stated can be solved via specialized techniques that apply  uniquely to bilinear varieties, a broader and deeper grounding is sought for this theorem within the context that modern algebraic geometry provides, with regard especially to techniques that extend naturally to generic multilinear algebraic varieties.  To borrow a phrase from Richard Hamming, "[The purpose of the question is insight, not theorems."](http://books.google.com/books?id=Y3YSCmWBVwoC&pg=PA4)

---

#### Quantum physics and engineering applications

In the context of quantum physics, $s$ may be regarded as an index over two $k$-dimensional Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$, each equipped with an $k$-element orthonormal basis, such that $(mn)$ is a multi-index over the quantum amplitudes $\psi_{(mn)}$ that are naturally associated to the $k^2$ orthonormal basis vectors of the bipartite Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$.

In quantum systems engineering (QSE), determinantal varieties are the bread-and-butter state-spaces of large-scale quantum simulations, because they support both the natural geometric pullback of [thermodynamical relations and conservation laws](http://faculty.washington.edu/sidles/FRIAS_2011/index.html#burningArrow) and the numerically efficient integration of dynamical trajectories that respect these relations.

---

#### The origin of the SHLT name

The name "SHLT" is a homage to the following dialog line in the film *Second Hand Lions:*

> **Uncle Garth** *(Michael McCaine):*  This lion's no good … it's … it's  …  *defective*.

The word *defective* refers specifically to a $\mathcal{M}^{(kk)\!}_{k{-}1}$ determinantal variety's one-dimensional (nonlinear) rank-defect as a quantum state-space, relative to the $k^2$-dimensional Hilbert space in which it is immersed (see below).

As a starting-point, the SHLT is mentioned — but regrettably only in passing and with no derivation given — in the paragraphs following Example 9.2 on [page 99 of Harris](http://books.google.com/books?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC&pg=PA99).

---

#### Two quantum physics conjectures

By definition, let a quantum state $\psi \in \mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ (so that $\dim \mathcal{H} = k^2$) be called *$k$-Lion* iff $\psi \in \mathcal{M}^{(kk)\!}_{k{-}1}$ (in Harris' notation for $\mathcal{M}\,$).

Then we have:

> **The Weak $k$-Lion Hypothesis**
>
> There exists a finite integer $k\lesssim 2^5$ such that no practicable quantum experiment can observationally disprove the hypothesis that the state-space of a symmetrically bipartite dynamical system is $k$-Lion rather than Hilbert.

Physically, the limit $k\lesssim 2^5$ corresponds to the case of quantum entanglement in a bipartite dynamical system having $5+5=10$ qubits in total.

The Weak $k$-Lion Hypothesis is sufficiently difficult to test — although by construction the required tests are far easier than demonstrating fault-tolerant quantum computing (FTLC) — that it is reasonable to suppose that Weak $k$-Lion Hypothesis cannot be feasibly be disconfirmed even for for quite small values of $k$.  Hence it is both mathematically and physically natural to conjecture:

> **The Strong $k$-Lion Hypothesis**
>
> There exists a constant of Nature in the form of a finite integer $k$, such that no experiment can observationally disprove the hypothesis that the state-space of a symmetrically bipartite dynamical system is $k$-Lion rather than Hilbert, for the fundamental reason that the dynamical state-space of Nature is a determinantal variety rather than a Hilbert space.

---

#### This question's <strike>three</strike> <strike>four</strike> five-level reward structure

Associated to this question is a <strike>three</strike> <strike>four</strike> five-level reward structure:

1. Gain MathOverflow reputation by providing good math literature references.
2. Contribute to the (wonderful) [ongoing GLL debate between Aram Harrow and Gil Kalai](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/flying-machines-of-the-21st-century/), and thereby help also to accelerate the medical goals of the [UW/ISH Naturality and Guidance Seminar](http://faculty.washington.edu/sidles/FRIAS_2011/index.html#NESTroadmap).
3. Demonstrate either $k$-Lion Hypothesis to [$100K wager on quantum computing">win $100,000 from Scott Aaronson](http://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/computing/hardware/why-im-wagering-100000-on-quantum-computing).
4. Receive MOF's first-ever award of the [Gold Reversal Medal](https://mathoverflow.net/badges/95/reversal).  Congratulations, Theo!
5. Best of all, the [Salmon Prize](http://www.dms.uaf.edu/~eallman/Papers/salmonPrize.pdf) is offered by mathematician/biologist [Elizabeth Allman](http://www.dms.uaf.edu/~eallman/Papers/IMAchallenge_and_reward.pdf).

Comment: I recommend making the title be less crass and have more class by omitting the dollar amount.  Gerhard "Likes Money, Doesn't Love It" Paseman, 2012.02.10

Comment: Gerhard, that is a fine suggestion ... it's done!

Comment: @John: How certain are you that your Hypotheses are equivalent to showing that "scalable quantum computing is impossible in the physical world"?  Your phrase "practicable quantum experiment" seems at odds with Scott's "impossible"...

Comment: Joseph, I think many folks are coming to appreciate that, when it comes to quantum computing, the boundaries between "possible", "infeasible", and "impossible" are not as mathematically or physically natural as everyone would like.  The SHLT question asked here on MOFL was conceived with a view toward illuminating some of the challenges associated to these boundaries.  Broadly, the idea is to get (hopefully) more clear on the mathematical foundations here at MOFL, then build upon those math foundations next week in science-and-engineering discussions on *Godel's Lost Letter*. 

Comment: Would someone please comment on why the aggressive downvoting?

Comment: @Andres Calcedo: the question is simply difficult to comprehend - it either reduces to a trivial linear algebraic fact (see Theo's answer) or involves some unspecified "algebraic constraints" which are not at all clear from the question. Plus, a lot of "background" (thermodynamics, quantum varieties, talk about pullbacks) makes it even more muddled, the relation to quantum computing is completely opaque (even for me, who does research in quantum computing), and frankly speaking, sentences with "STEM" being every other word don't seem to hep.

Comment: In short, the question would be much better if OP cut all the hype about STEM, lions, $100,000 rewards, scalable quantum computing etc. and left the underlying mathematical question clear and well defined (in particular, it should be obvious why the question is not trivial).

Comment: I started a meta thread here : http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1307/question-about-second-hand-lions-quantum-dynamics-etc/  Please vote this up so that it becomes more visible.

Comment: Please let me say that I consider the various comments on my question to have been (all of them) very valuable, and so later today (Sunday) I will post an amended version that attempts to address these comments all-at-once.  Especially I appreciate and am grateful for Theo Johnson-Freyd's comments---as pertaining both narrowly to notation and broadly to mathematical context---and it has been *exceedingly* enjoyable to watch this question help Theo (albeit inadvertently) earn MOF's first Gold Reversal Medal.  So thank you all very much!

Comment: I agree with Marcin. The question is still much, much too long.

Comment: @Qiaochu your suggestion is sound, and in response the question now is shortened, focused, and now begins with a suggested answer than draws upon Joseph Landsberg's very recent (and dauntingly comprehensive) monograph *Tensors: Geometry and Applications* (December 2011). It turns out too that certain key results are accessibly surveyed in Landsberg's *Bull. AMS* article "Geometry and the complexity of matrix multiplication" (2008). These essentially are the references sought, and so I thank you and everyone here on MOF for comments and suggestions that have helped in finding them.

Comment: What could be very helpful for understanding the question is a simple overview of the background and down to earth description of the conjecture. It looks that John is referring to a method, (perhaps even a method used in practice) to replace a large Hilbert state space of a quantum system by a much lower dimensional algebraic variety of some sort. Taking this variety as a the space of states you can still (but I dont understand how) discuss quantum-like evolutions. John's conjecture is that such much lower dimensional approximation give a good approximation to practical quantum evoltions. 

Comment: @Gil Kalai and @Marcin Kotowski, you are *both* entirely correct.  The question asked arose when our UW QSE Group noticed certain numerical "miracles" in our quantum spin simulation software. In this regard, please let me commend in Joseph Landsberg's book *Tensors: Geometry and Applications* his short essay of Section 0.3, titled "Clash of Cultures" (http://books.google.com/books?id=JTjv3DTvxZIC&pg=PR17). Thus, next week I hope to post a focused question to help reconcile these cultures, in accord with Hestenes' saying: "Geometry without algebra is dumb, algebra without geometry is blind."

Comment: @John: I do not think that MO questions should be geared towards reconciling cultures. That's what blog posts are for. 

Comment: @Qiaochu, in agreement with your point, the unique virtue of MOF surely is its exclusive focus upon well-posed math questions. And yet in agreement too with Gil Kalai, many folks (but not all) appreciate physical/practical motivations. And finally (in my own opinion) it is neither necessary, nor feasible, nor even desirable that everyone think & post alike in these matters. So to strike a three-way balance, my *next* post will be a double-distilled pure-math question, whose physical/practical motivations are described separately, below a bar (where folks can ignore them or not, as preferred).

Comment: As an update, a key reference regarding quantum dynamics on projective varieties turns out to be Hirotachi Abo; Giorgio Ottaviani; Chris Peterson, "Induction for secant varieties of Segre varieties", *Transactions of the AMS* (2008).  Combining the proof technologies of Abo *et al.* with numerical experiments via our quantum systems engineering software yields a plausible conjecture for a complete classification of "lion" varieties, and this conjectured varietal classification will be the subject of an MOL question in the next couple of weeks. 

Comment: As a further update, it turns out that the Salmon Prize is offered for progress in this class of conjecture, and the question-asked now links to this prize.

Comment: Some progress towards Salmon Conjecture was made and I can attest that at least one of the authors received a portion of Alaskan salmon from Dr. Altman in recognition of the contribution: 

A proof of the set-theoretic version of the salmon conjecture 
Shmuel Friedland, Elizabeth Gross 
arXiv.org > math > arXiv:1104.1776 

The question itself and the problems it concerns are well beyond my expertise and interests, but I happen to be married to Shmuel... 

Answer (score 35):

I can't comment on the Lion hypotheses.  I'm pretty sure the SHLT is nothing more than the fact that:

> A linear endormophism of a $k$-dimensional vector space factors through a $(k-1)$-dimensional vector space iff it has nontrivial kernel iff its determinant is $0$.

Stated without all the indices, this is completely obvious to any mathematician.  So I predict that understanding the SHLT will not help you to prove your Lion hypotheses.

Comment: @Theo, in the main I agree with you entirely.  It's true that (in your phrase) the SHLT is "completely obvious" to all STEM professionals who have worked through the first 99 pages of Joe Harris' *Algebraic Geometry*. Yet *that* is a very tiny subset of STEM professionals, and this reflects the paucity of terms like "practical, physics, engineering, dynamics, simulation" (which appear not at all in Harris). What is *not* obvious (to mathematicians especially) are the transformational applications of Harris' methods. And so I have added a link (to "thermodynamical relations") in this regard.

Comment: What is a "STEM professional"?

Comment: STEM = "Science, Technology, Engineering, and Mathematics" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STEM_fields)

Comment: Hm. But the displayed statement of Theo is something that anyone who's taken a good course on linear algebra should be able to prove... Surely STEM professionals have taken a linear algebra course, no?

Comment: The short answer is "no."  It is rather like saying, surely STEM professionals have taken a good course on thermodynamics, no?  Surely STEM professionals have taken a good course on differential forms, no?  Surely STEM professionals have taken a good course on complexity classes, no?  An enjoyably hilarious polemic on this subject is Bill Burke's <i>samizdat</i> classic *Div, Grad, Curl are Dead* (http://www.ucolick.org/~burke/home.html).

Comment: The linear algebra course doesn't even have to be that good - I put problems like that on my matrix-algebra-for-engineers exams and the decent students usually get them right.

Comment: @John: One thing that I think is hard for the mathematicians here to process is that you keep referring to Harris _Algebraic Geometry_, which is a GTM and not in an easy subject. I might have misunderstood what you mean the second-hand lion theorem to mean, but my understanding of it is a theorem we teach in second-year calculus to every STEM major. (It is somewhat disappointing to hear that they so quickly forget it!) Conversely, typically 100 pages of a GTM is most of a semester of a graduate-level class. For example, I have never read Harris, nor any textbook on algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Theo, please let me say that I have great respect for your contributions here on MOFL.  However, it seems (to me) that the answer you posted here is the correct answer to a completely different question than was asked.  Doesn't it seem odd to you that "a theorem we teach in second-year calculus to every STEM major" gets an entire chapter in Harris' (high-level graduate) text?   That is why it would help a great deal if your answer specified explicitly *what* vector spaces and endomorphisms you were referring to!  You might find the question asked is subtler than your initial impression of it.

Comment: @Theo, I have added a technical caveat regarding linearity to the question, in the hope that you might augment your answer to address it... in which event it would be my pleasure to upvote your suggested answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @John Sidles: if you interpret $\psi$ as a $k\times k$ matrix then the lhs of SHLT can be read as saying that each of the $k$ row vectors of $\psi$ is a linear combination of the $k-1$ vectors $\xi_{1r}$. Which is the same as saying that they must be linearly dependent or $\det \psi=0$.

Comment: I'm giving a +1 to Theo for a frivolous reason: to bring him closer to a gold reversal badge. (I haven't thought hard whether it completely answers the question, but the last sentence does seem reasonable to me.) 

Comment: Michael, your $\Rightarrow$ argument is entirely correct, and the $\Leftarrow$ implication is no harder ... e.g., the SVD of a zero-determinant $\psi$ must have at least one zero principal value, such that the SVD constructs a (non-unique) solution set of $k-1$ pairs `$\{\xi_{1r},\xi_{2r}\}$` ... but such constructions are *not* the answer to the question asked (which was a request for references) and neither do they correspond to the answer that Theo supplied (to be sure, Theo's answer was well-reasoned, but it did not address the question asked). 

Comment: @John: one does not need the SVD for the converse implication, it is a fundamental property of the determinant: if $\det \psi =0$ then the rows\columns of the matrix must be linearly dependent, and so span at most a k-1 dimensional subspace. So really any book on linear algebra probably proves what you call the SHLT. I think this is what Theo was saying.

Comment: @John: Yes, it does seem very odd. Which is why I hope I've been careful to say that it's likely I've misinterpreted your question. Indeed, your question is _really_ asking about your Lion hypotheses, about which I can make no contributions. As written, the SHLT doesn't make any sense --- the LHS of the equation refers to vectors $\xi$ whereas the RHS does not. So I interpreted it as "Given $\psi$ a tensor with two indices ranging from $1$ to $k$, there exists $\xi$ with indices ... such that $\psi = \xi\xi$ iff $\det \psi = 0$." That was the statement I rewrote in my answer. I maintain that 

Comment: _that_ statement is in any undergraduate linear algebra textbook, with all of the conditions you ask for at the top of your question. As a representation theorist, I am very aware that there is a lot to be said about the (algebraic) geometry of solutions to such equations. I assume (without having read Harris) that that's what Harris discusses, and not the (in the 21st century) essentially trivial fact that the existence of $\xi$ satisfying the LHS is controlled by the determinant of $\psi$.

Comment: @Theo and @Todd (and others), thank you for your considerate remarks!  Per Theo's request, I will clarify the question's notation and characterize more precisely the type of reference that is desired. My access to Harris' text via Google Books is (frustratingly!) partial, yet for quantum systems engineers (QSEs) the intent is captured by Harris' passage (page 100) "We should draw a fundamental and important distinction between bi- and tri- or multilinear objects." In practice, QSEs require a mathematical toolset that extends naturally to the multilinear algebraic objects of Harris' remark.

Comment: @Theo and @Todd (and others), the amended question has now been posted, and in particular it quotes a passage from Harris' textbook that addresses the "odd circumstance" that questions regarding bilinear algebraic varieties commonly can be answered by elementary methods, yet the analogous questions for generic multilinear varieties are deep. The amended question seeks to clarify that the state-spaces of practical concern to quantum systems engineers nowadays, and hence the mathematical tools of greatest interest, are associated to generic multilinear varieties. Thank you all very much! :)

Comment: @Theo and @Todd, on further literature review it turns out that the Salmon Prize is offered for progress in this class of conjecture, and the question now links to this prize.