# Quantum dynamics on varieties: asymptotic quantum trace distance on SHL varieties

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

#### The Question Asked

> **Definition: the Second-Hand Lion trace distance $D_k$**
>
> Let $\mathcal{M}^{(kk)}_r$ be the set of $k\times k$ complex matrices of rank $\le r$ having unit trace norm. Then the *Second-Hand Lion [trace distance](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0408063)* $D_k$ is by definition
>   $$D_k = 
>    \max_{M_1\in \mathcal{M}^{(kk)}_k}\ \,
>    \min_{M_2\in \mathcal{M}^{(kk)}_{k{-}1}}\ \,\tfrac{1}{2} \text{tr}\,|M_1-M_2|$$

The question asked is, what is the asymptotic behavior of $D_k$ for $k\gg1$?

---

#### Physics and Engineering Motivation

The set $\mathcal{M}^{(kk)}_k$ is isomorphic to the quantum Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^{k^2}$, and the set $\mathcal{M}^{(kk)}_{k{-}1}$ is an determinantal variety that we shall call the *SHL variety of order $k-1$*; and the SHL variety has a natural embedding in the larger Hilbert space.

Moreover the [Second-Hand Lion Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88133/harris-algebraic-geometry-quantum-dynamics-on-varieties-and-a-more-than-mone) assures us:

- The SHL variety of order $k-1$ has dimension $k^2-1$, that is, the SHL variety lacks precisely *one* dimension with respect to the embedding Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^{k^2}$.
- The SHL variety of order $k-1$ is naturally equipped with algebraic coordinates that are well-suited to the efficient numerical integration of trajectories (both metric and symplectic) on the SHL variety.

Physically the question asked therefore amounts to this: For quantum states adversarially chosen within a $k\times k$ Hilbert space, what is the worst-case quantum fidelity with which that Hilbert state can be approximated as an SHL varietal state of order $k-1$?

This question is motivated partly by numerical experiments that indicate (for example) $D_8 \simeq 0.0568$. A reasonable conjecture (for example) may be $D_k = \mathcal{O}\,(1/k)$.

---

#### Broader Motivations

More broadly, the question asked was conceived with a view toward illuminating the general problems of approximating Hilbert-space dynamics with varietal dynamics, in regard to the mathematically natural, physically fundamental, computationally practicable (and perennially surprising) features of these varietal dynamical systems.

Comment: Hi John, This looks like an improved version of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88133/, but I haven't read the question closely so I'm not sure if they are asking the same thing or are two questions on the same topic (certainly it's great to ask a series of related questions!). If the former, you can probably leave a link to this question at the top of the old one, and close the old one yourself; if you can't close it yourself, I'm sure you can leave a comment on meta asking it be closed. If the latter, then I hope you get good answers to both questions!

Comment: A mathematical clarification question: You define the matrices in $\mathcal M_r^{(kk)}$ as "having unit trace norm", which is not a phrase I often come across --- I could imagine it meaning "unit trace", or "unit (matrix) norm", or.... But then you say that $\mathcal M_k^{(kk)}\cong\mathbb C^{k^2}$, so it seems that this condition is vacuous.  In any case, am I right to think that the distance is asking "how far can a full-rank matrix be from any lower-rank matrix?"? If so, then you certainly do want some condition, or to normalize the distance somehow, else you get the answer $D_k=\infty$....

Comment: ... I will have to read the linked paper to understand why absolute-value-of-trace is the natural distance (I assume this is what you mean --- I don't know how to take the trace of "the absolute value of a matrix"), and not some other matrix norm that seems more natural to me (e.g. Hilbert-Schmidt norm). But probably for the maximum asymptotics you don't care, because there are probably AM-GM style inequalities. Anyway, once $\mathcal M_r^{(kk)}$ is made somehow compact or the norm is otherwise normalized, I like this question a lot.